# Run docker-compose in SpringBoot with MySQL: Database is not connected to Spring Application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, hibernate

I have a Microservice (Product Service) in SpringBoot, and a Database in MySQL and want to run my Application in Docker

I can run the service locally without any errors. But when I start with Docker (docker-compose up --build), it shows some errors with the connection.

I show my codes in application.properties, Dockerfile, docker-compose, pom.xml and the errors. After some changes and asking friends, the errors are still there. I would be grateful if someone could help me :)

In MySQL Workbench I set a connection with URL `localhost:3306` and create a schema `testdb` inside.

This is my `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
spring.datasource.username= abc
spring.datasource.password= def
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

#Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

This is Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src

RUN mvn install -DskipTests
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=/app/target/dependency
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.example.helloworld.EcommerceApplication"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

This is docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  product-service:
    container_name: product-service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - database
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/testdb
      #- SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=abc
      #- SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=def
      - SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO=update
      - SPRING_JPA_SHOW-SQL= true
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - internal

  database:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql
    #ports:
    #  - "3306:3307"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: abc
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: def 

    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  internal:
    name: internal
```

This is my dependencies in pom.xml

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I summerize errors in these codes

`product-service    | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

```
`product-service    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

`product-service    | 2023-03-14 08:45:26.585  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/a
utoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution`

`product-service    | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/b
oot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution`

`product-service    | Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
`

`product-service    | Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
`

`product-service    | 2023-03-14 08:50:17.188 ERROR 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
`

`product-service    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
`
```

product-service    |    ... 52 common frames omitted

Comment: Probably add '?useSSL=false' in your connection string?

Comment: I added to application.properties and docker-compose. They are not possible either

Answer (score 0):

In docker-compose file your DB container is named `database` and same name should be used as a hostname when accessing this container within your network

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://database:3306/testdb
and
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/testdb
```

instead of

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
and 
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/testdb
```

Comment: In docker-compose my database container's name is mysql. In this case URL should be jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/testdb

In application.properties I set spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb. Because MySQL Connection has port localhost:3306, service can be run locally only with hostname localhost. I tried database instead of locahost. It doesn't work with local run.

To be sure I changed hostname like your comment, and also try jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/testdb. Both are not possible